# JavaScript event listener is not working with if statement

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container div with many smaller divs inside of it, each with a class of box. The container is styled as a grid. I have an event listener that changes the background color of the grid boxes when there is a mouseover event.

I want to make a psychedelic mode that makes the boxes a random color when there is a mouse over instead of a fixed color.

I have a button:

```
 <button class="psychMode">Psychedelic Mode</button>
```

It is identified in the JavaScript:

```
let psych = document.querySelector('.psychMode');
let psychClass = psych.getAttribute('class');
```

I have a toggle on the class of the button to change it to `psychMode active` when the button is clicked:

```
psych.addEventListener('click', function () {
    psych.classList.toggle('active');
})
```

Finally, I have a function that returns a random number and the event listeners for the boxes:

```
function randomColor() {
    let num= Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    return num;
}

let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box')

for (let i of boxes) {
    i.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        i.style['backgroundColor'] = 'black'
        i.style.border = '1px solid red'
    })
}

for (let i of boxes) {
    if (psychClass === 'active') {
        i.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
            i.style['backgroundColor'] = `rgb(${randomColor()},${randomColor()},${randomColor()})`
            i.style.border = `1px solid rgb(${randomColor()},${randomColor()},${randomColor()})`
        })
    }
}
```

For some reason, the code only results in a black background and red border. It doesn't choose a random color even when the active class is toggled on. I also tried putting both conditionals in the for loop together, it still didn't work. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you accessing `background-color` with bracket notation? and accessing `border` with dot notation? It would make more sense to assign `i.style.backgroundColor = "stuff"` or keep things consistent by choosing one or the other.

Comment: Can you show a basic version of your HTML. Will help us reproduce it.

Comment: I'm a beginner, was just experimenting and forgot to change the notation back @TannerDolby. You are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (let i of boxes) {
    i.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        if(!psych.classList.contains("active"){
          i.style.backgroundColor = 'black'
          i.style.border = '1px solid red'
        }else{
          i.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${randomColor()},${randomColor()},${randomColor()})`
          i.style.border = `1px solid rgb(${randomColor()},${randomColor()},${randomColor()})`
        }
    })
}
```

use this instead of those 2 for loops.

make your code as concise as possible and avoid unnecessary loops.

Answer (score 0):

You're only ever assigning `psychClass` once, so it always equals `"psychMode"`.

You'd be better off ditching that variable altogether and going with [`Element.classList.contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) (for the specifics of the `contains` function, [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains))

```js
function randomColor() {
    let num= Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    return num;
}

let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box')

for (let i of boxes) {
    i.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        i.style['backgroundColor'] = 'black'
        i.style.border = '1px solid red'
    })
}

for (let i of boxes) {
    if (psych.classList.contains('active')) {
        i.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
            i.style['backgroundColor'] = `rgb(${randomColor()},${randomColor()},${randomColor()})`
            i.style.border = `1px solid rgb(${randomColor()},${randomColor()},${randomColor()})`
        })
    }
}
```